# How do I enable Intellitest in VisualStudio 2015 RC?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, visual-studio-2015

I installed the Visual Studio 2015 RC and tried to "Run Intelltest" as per the instructions on the [Microsoft Help Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn823749(v=vs.140).aspx), but the command doesn't appear on the popup menu as expected.  Does anyone have any idea what happened?  Was it pulled from the RC, or do I have to set a flag / configuration item, do an extra install, etc.  Any help in this regard would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Run IntelliTest command should show up for C# apps created from project templates under the Windows Desktop hive in the File | New | Project dialog.

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for your suggestion.  Unfortunately, though, the command didn't show up when I followed your instructions

Comment: This is intriguing. Would you be willing to provide more details about the project and code fragment on which you tried launching the command so that we can investigate this and get back?

Comment: It turns out that Intellitest works for old-style C# apps like "Class Library" but not the new C# apps like "Class Library (Package)".  I'll put in a bug report...

Comment: Does not seem to work.
Not sure why it should be necessary to do this with a Windows Desktop project type, rather than a website / web application project?

Answer (score 1):

You should download the Enterprise version of RC, not the Professional.

Comment: I did download the Enterprise version, from the Visual Studio 2015 RC page, but no luck

Comment: The old Ultimate version is now called "Enterprise".